# Is there any way to clear django.db.connection.queries?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, reset

I want to monitor query time in my system(built with `Django models`).

Finally, I found `django.db.connection.queries`.

It shows all queries and time taking for it.

Using this, I want to print the list of which I have done queries at regular interval and then I want to clear the list I printed after printing.

It seems to have methods for a list object(`pop, remove` and so on).

But Even though I call `pop()`, It doesn't have any effect, still showing the same length.

How can I clear the list..?

Or Is there any other methods for my intention?

p.s I also found `Django-debug-toolbar` but it seems only for view part.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can call `reset_queries()` from the django.db module.

```
from django.db import reset_queries
reset_queries()
```

Comment: Also see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`reset_queries()`** to clear `connection.queries`.

For example, if putting **`reset_queries()`** after **`Person.objects.select_for_update()`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.db import reset_queries
from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    Person.objects.create(name="John") # INSERT
    
    qs = Person.objects.select_for_update().get(name="John") # SELECT FOR UPDATE
    reset_queries() # Here
    qs.name = "Tom"
    qs.save() # UPDATE
    qs.delete() # DELETE
                 
    for query in connection.queries: # Here
        print(query)

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

You get only **`UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries** without **`INSERT` and `SELECT FOR UPDATE` queries** as shown below:

```
{'sql': 'UPDATE "store_person" SET "name" = \'Tom\' WHERE "store_person"."id" = 190', 'time': '0.000'}
{'sql': 'DELETE FROM "store_person" WHERE "store_person"."id" IN (190)', 'time': '0.000'}
[24/Dec/2022 07:00:01] "GET /store/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9
```